# Error: index beyond bounds

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

I have been getting the error of index beyond bounds.

I have been dealing with ZLSwipeableView Swift Version.

The code

```
 import UIKit

   class SwipeableViewController: UIViewController  {

         var swipeAbleView : ZLSwipeableView!

                override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
                    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
                    swipeAbleView.nextView = {
                     return self.nextCardView()
                    }
                }

// This is the colors array
                var colors : NSArray = NSArray(array: [UIColor.orangeColor() , UIColor.blueColor() , UIColor.greenColor() , UIColor.blackColor() , UIColor.brownColor() , UIColor.magentaColor()])

             var v : UIView!

             var cardsCount = 6
             var cardsIndex = 0

              override func viewDidLoad() {
                    super.viewDidLoad()

                    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

                    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
                    view.clipsToBounds = true

                    swipeAbleView = ZLSwipeableView()
                    swipeAbleView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)
                    self.swipeAbleView.alpha = 0.0

                    UIView.animateWithDuration (0.25, delay: 0.35, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear ,animations: {
                        self.swipeAbleView.alpha = 1.0
                        }, completion:nil)
                    self.view.addSubview(swipeAbleView)


                    self.swipeAbleView.discardViews()
                    self.swipeAbleView.loadViews()
                }

                func nextCardView() -> UIView {

                    if cardsIndex < cardsCount {

                    cardsIndex += 1
                    }

                    let cardView = CardView(frame: self.swipeAbleView.bounds)
// The error occurs here and the app crashes
                    cardView.backgroundColor = colors[cardsIndex] as? UIColor

                    return cardView

                }
            }
```

The error occurs when I define the color for the cardView.

The application crashes I get the error.

Answer (score 3):

```
if cardsIndex < cardsCount {
    cardsIndex += 1
}
```

This condition does not prevent you from going over the bounds, the correct condition would be:

```
if cardsIndex + 1 < cardsCount {
    cardsIndex += 1
}
```

Although I would consider very strange to change data from `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 0):

The clear answer here is to write an extension for integer that clamps the value

```
extension Int {
    func clamp(minRange: Int, maxRange: Int) {
        self = min(maxRange, self)
        self = max(minRange, self)
    }
}
```

then do this

```
cardsIndex.clamp(0, cardsIndex + 1)
```

Comment: please don't actually do this, if you feel the need to make something like this, then make it return a new Int not modify self... this was more or a troll answer XD

Comment: If you actually wanted to do this (and the `clamp` function is useful sometimes) then you should definitely use `Range<Int>`. You might actually put that as an extension on `Range<T>`, accepting a value of `T` and then calling `(0..<20).clamp(30)`.

Comment: Actually, there's already a clamp function baked into The Metal API (not that you can't make it far simpler and more intuitive) https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Metal/Reference/MetalShadingLanguageGuide/std-lib/std-lib.html.